# How automatically read every seconds an imported via <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, html, input, web-worker

Is it possible to load a file via a tag `<input file="type">` and then automatically load and read it every seconds without any user action (via a webworker or anything else) ?

The idea to display in live a file in the browser.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions about that ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you rephrase your question and add more details on what you're looking for?

Comment: Also, are you perhaps just looking for `setInterval()`, or something more complicated?

Comment: There is no way to automatically read a file from a user's computer using JavaScript inside a web browser. It would require the user specify a file in a form every single time.